# Laravel count-function in Model, then sortBy count()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to Order the `Posts` table by the number of votes a `Post` has got.
The votes are stored in an other table

```
(Votes: post_id, user_id, vote_type)
```

Post-Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
      return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }

    public function votes()
    {
      return DB::table('votes')->where('post_id','=',$this->id)->sum('vote_type');
    }
}
```

The votes functions returns the number of votes a post has recieved(The Votes a stored in a seperate table)

Now I am trying to order all the `Posts` by the number of votes they have got.

```
Post::get()->sortBy('votes');
```

This returns follwing Error:

> Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

I would be thankful about any help to fix this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give it a try

```
Post::get()->sortBy(function($query){
return $query->votes();
});
```

**Alternative**

You can use [withCount()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) as it will place a `{relation}_count` column on your resulting models.

```
Post::withCount(['votes'])
->orderBy('votes_count')
->get()
```

**For Pagination**

Refer [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination#paginating-eloquent-results) for more details on paginations

```
Post::withCount(['votes'])
->orderBy('votes_count')
->paginate();
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't work: It return following error:
`Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation`
This is because the votes() method returns an integer.

Comment: try now I have forgot () there

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Do you know if there is any possability to paginate the result, as it is an instance of collection

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function in your Post Model

```
 protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope('voteCount', function ($builder) {
            $builder->withCount('votes');
        });
    }
```

Now, each of your post model will always have a voteCount value and You can sort on that.

In your controller, use:

```
Post::get()->sortBy('voteCount');
```

Keep in mind that this will always return a votesCount with the PostModel, but I'm assuming it will be required as it usually does in this kind of applications.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to sort votes as a attribute you have to to make it to be attribute by adding `getVotesAttribute()` method in your `Post` Model.

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
      return $this->hasOne(User::class);
    }

    public function getVotesAttribute()
    {
      return DB::table('votes')->where('post_id','=',$this->id)->sum('vote_type');
    }
}
```

Comment: When you will want to display last 100 posts and their votes, will you execute this query for each post you want to print on screen? How will you sort it?

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek If you want to display 100 last posts just do

`Post::limit(100)->latest()->->get()->sortBy('votes');` 

what is the problem?

Comment: You sort it by query execution, it means you would execute the getVotesAttribute query 100 times as you need to make a query for each model to sort it out. If you don't see the problem then try to use 3 solutions like this on single page and think why loading of the pages takes more than 3 seconds